# Handling asynchronous programming with Ramda

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

I am looking at handling functions that return promises with Ramda functions other then pipeP. I am trying to compare functions (one of which returns a promise) with equals like this:

```
getSectionFromDb :: obj -> promise
getSectionFromData :: obj -> number

R.equals(
    getSectionFromDb,
    getSectionFromData
)
```

There are two factors at play here. First R.equals will not evaluate functions, but the bigger issue is that I'm comparing a promise to a number.

Is there a functional way of doing this kind of stuff (I know the functions are not referential transparent, but there must be a way of dealing with io)? Is there a Ramda way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sound like you want to `lift` the `equals` function - first in the promise monad and then in the function applicative; unfortunately Ramda can only lift for lists.

Comment: So you want a function `??? :: (obj -> Promise<number>) -> (obj -> number) -> (obj -> Promise<boolean>)`?

Comment: @Bergi: Ramda's documentation is not quite up to snuff here, but `lift` **[does work on arbitrary `Applicative Functors`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/test/liftN.js#L42-L45)**.

Comment: So it should be something like `liftN(2, flip(compose(map, equals)))` assuming that your functions implement `Applicative` [like this](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/master/Function.js#L188) and your Promises implement `Functor`

Comment: That is helpful. I understand conceptually that we need to change the equals to `??? :: (obj -> Promise<number>) -> (obj -> number) -> (obj -> Promise<boolean>)` but I am not sure syntactically how lift should work.

Comment: Note, BTW, that most implementations of `Promise` do **not** implement `Functor`.  Some, such as [pacta](https://libraries.io/npm/pacta#user-content-promisemapf) do.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want.  Do you want to run `equals` on the result of the resolved promise and the return of the other function, once they're both available?  If so, then you might want something like `Promise.all`  Ramda doesn't work much with Promises, as they tend not to be very lawful.  If you were using a `Future` or `Task` implementation, this might be more clear.

Comment: Well I do kind of have two questions here. I would like to compare the resolved value of a promise with a  returned value of a function. Also I would like to know how to handle asynchronous JavaScript features in a functional manor. It looks like Ramda might not be the best tool for that. I'll have a look at Future and Task

Comment: I'd really recommend using RxJS with Asynchronous issues. I know that doesn't answer your question but it's great library and you can easily use it with Ramda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Promise.resolve` to "wrap" a value in a promise.

```
getSectionFromDataPromise :: obj -> promise
getSectionFromDataPromise = R.pipe(getSectionFromData , (val) => Promise.resolve(val))
```

This way you can promote (lift) any function that returns a normal value to a one that returns a promise.

Lifting is an essential concept in FP. You can view `Array.map` as a function that lifts a function that transforms a value to a function that transforms an array of values.

You can use `Promise.all` to write a function that compares promises and (for example) throws an error if they are not equal.

```
function promiseEquals (f1, f2) {
  return Promise.all([f1(), f2()]).then(function(vals) {
    if(!R.equals(vals[0], vals[1])) {throw "The values aren't equal"}
    return vals[0]
  })
}
```

Lastly you can combine the two:

```
promiseEquals(getSectionFromDataPromise, getSectionFromDb)
  .then(function(val){
    console.log(val)
  })
  .catch(function(val){console.log("Error "+val)})
```

Comment: Isn't (val) => Promise.resolve(val) just a verbose way of saying Promise.resolve  ?

Comment: ideally yes, in JS no. The resolve function is not bound to the Promise object.

Comment: @arcseldon You could do `getSectionFromDataPromise = R.pipe(getSectionFromData, Promise.resolve.bind(Promise));`

Answer (score 14):

I know, the question is old. But ramda has some cool functions to compose Promise-returning functions: [pipeP](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#pipeP) and [composeP](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#composeP).

Also take a look into regular [compose](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#compose) ([pipe](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#pipe)) and it's Kleisli implementation [composeK](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#composeK) ([pipeK](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#pipeK)). They allow to work with algebraic structures like Future or Task, which look the same as Promise, but lazy-evaluated.

Comment: As of 0.26.0, pipeP and composeP got deprecated in favor of https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith and https://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeWith

Comment: @VincentTaing Do you know of any examples that get data from a url?

Answer (score 7):

`pipeP` and `composeP` got deprecated.

Create `pipeWithPromise` which accepts an array of promises or functions.

```js
var pipeWithPromise = R.pipeWith((fun, previousResult) => (previousResult && previousResult.then) ? previousResult.then(fun) : fun(previousResult));
var tasks = [/* sync func */ $ => $ + '1', /* async func */ async $ => await $ + '2'];
var result = await pipeWithPromise(tasks)('state');
// result = 'state12';
```

Comment: these are deprecated since ramda 0.26

Answer (score 1):

It's not ramda, but it'll do what you want

```js
const { eq } = require('rubico')
/*
getSectionFromDb :: obj -> promise
getSectionFromData :: obj -> number
*/
eq(
  getSectionFromDb,
  getSectionFromData
)({...}) // => Promise { true }
```

rubico's eq will resolve promises under the hood, so the promise you get from `getSectionFromDb` will be resolved before it is compared with the number from `getSectionFromData`. The return value will be a Promise of a boolean that you'll have to resolve elsewhere, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom compose: https://gist.github.com/ehpc/2a524b78729ee6b4e8111f89c66d7ff5